# Converting multiple character variables to numbers in if statement

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

I'm trying to take user inputted words (black, red, green, blue) and change them into integers (1, 2, 3, 4) using an "if" statement. Pretty new to programming so any explanations welcome. The code below tells me "comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour" and always goes to the "else" factor, to give me 4.

variable declared:

```
int calccol = 0;
char usercol[5];
```

user inputs color choice:

```
std::cout << "Pick a color: " ;
 std::cout << "\n Black \n Red \n Green \n Blue \nYour color choice: " ;
 std::cin >> usercol ;
```

failing if statement:

```
if (usercol == "black") {
      calccol = calccol + 1;
  } else if (usercol == "red") {
      calccol = calccol + 2;
  } else if (usercol == "green"){
      calccol = calccol + 3;
  } else {
      calccol = calccol + 4;
  } ;

   std::cout << calccol ;
```

I want the calccol value to be for example 3 when the user inputs the word "green".

Comment: `char usercol[5];` doesn't have enough space to store both five letters *and* a null terminator. In addition, comparing `char*` with `==` does not compare the values of the strings they point to. It just checks if they point to the same address (they won't in this case).

Comment: Partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674309/c-strings-matching-returning-false I'm looking for another one that addresses the buffer being too small.

Comment: Have you gotten [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1)? It's absolutely essential.

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare `char*` for equality like that. You'd have to use `strcmp` and see if the result is `0`. But since this is C++, why not use `std::string` instead? Just change this line:

```
char usercol[5];
```

To this:

```
std::string usercol;
```

And it works as expected.

---

Here's how it would work with C style strings instead:
First, you need to make sure the buffer is big enough, which it previously wasn't:

```
char usercol[10]; // has to be big enough to hold the choice
```

In this example its size is `10`, that's 9 for the entered text and `1` for the null-terminator that signalizes the end of the string. One problem is that a (possibly malicious) user could enter an even bigger string, causing that buffer to overflow which is undefined behavior and will possibly cause memory corruption. More complicated workarounds are necessary to prevent that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617853/10411602) for an example.

Next, you need to fix the comparisons. `usercol == "black"` won't work because that compares the buffer's address to the address of a hardcoded `"black"` that is put in the program's executable. They will never match. Instead, [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) has to be used like this:

```
if (!strcmp(usercol, "black")) {...
```

`strcmp` returns `0` if the strings are equal and something else otherwise. Those will implicitly be cast to `false` and `true` respectively. By adding the `!` in front of it, reversing it. This gives us the desired result: `if (!strcmp(usercol, "black"))` is `true` if `usercol`'s string content is the same as the one of `"black"`.

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid not knowing this. But just so I know for next time, could you explain the use of strcmp and the * used after char?

Comment: @Universe31 `strcmp` won't work here. It only works with character strings which requires that the string end with a null terminator. You need a `char` to hold it. You'll have to first make `usercol` one larger than the largest string you want it to store.

Comment: @Universe31 glad it helped. It's commendable that you're also interested about the C style solution, so I added an explanation about how to do it with `char` arrays and `strcmp`.